# How can I use create-react-app with Spring Boot?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I'm trying to serve a ReactJS app together with an API built with Spring Boot. I've run the script `create-react-app` on /public/ - as shown on the structure below - however, all relative paths from ReactJS seems to be broken when I try to access it from http://localhost:8080/public/index.html

What else do I need to do in order to correctly load the resources from ReactJS?

[image]

Answer (score 16):

I suggest you create two projects:

- one for your Spring Boot backend;
- one for your React frontend, created with `create-react-app`.

In dev mode, you have to run the React development server with node: 'npm start'.
You should define a proxy to your Spring Boot app: `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080",` to add to your `package.json`. Documentation of this mechanism is [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#proxying-api-requests-in-development).
And you can execute your backend as usual with Gradle: `./gradlew bootRun`.

In production deployment, you can generate a build of your React app with `npm run build`. The static files produced by `create-react-app` can be placed in a static directory in your Spring Boot application, for instance in `src/main/resources/static/` ([docs about static content](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content) with Spring Boot)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome, I'll test it! Thank you very much

Comment: NB if you go down this road you need to bear in mind that in the production system it is a good idea to bundle them together using Docker, so that both systems are started on the same host and the configured proxy continues to work in production without needing to mess around with editing the package.json during the build process.